# How can i know the that in which class button is created which has generated event....?

Tags: java, swing

Acctaully i am implementing Model-View-Controller(MVC) and in controller class i have to know which view's JButton have fired event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) method of the event:

```
Object source = event.getSource();
if (source == button1) {
    ...
}
else if (source == button2) {
    ...
}
```

But you should probably avoid having a single ActionListener handle the events from multiple buttons in the first place. Each button should have its own responsibility, and hence be handled by a single listener.

Comment: @Arsalan  I did not understand your comment.  What do you mean by 'compare with which'?

Comment: @JB Nizet if (event.getSource() == ???? )
with which i have to compare because my event handling class is different and that button is not accessible in that class...

My View class have button (which have fired event) and i am handling that event in my Controller class.

Comment: Then set an action command in your buttons, and use `getActionCommand()` on the event to get it. But my point reamains: if each button had its own listener, the responsibilities would be cleaner, and you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks...but if each button have its own listener then what about MVC...?

Comment: I don't know. It depends what you mean with MVC, and how you implement it. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to advise.